# Custom scroll UX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I'm currently working on a project where the desired user experience involves a very customized interaction with scroll events.

**Problem to solve:** 
The page has X sections, each of them with a height equal to the viewport hight `height: 100vh;`.  When a user scrolls down on the viewport, the current visible section stays where it is and a scroll indicator animates based on a threshold of distance scrolled (30px, for example).  Once the user has scrolled the threshold, the next section comes up from the bottom of the screen and covers up the current section (which still doesn't move).

**Initial Approach:** 
Set each section to an absolute position and adjust them with by changing CSS classes based on the `scrollwheel` event. Body `overflow:hidden` and `transform` property to manipulate the sections. I am running in to issues, though.

1. The scrollwheel event seems to be documented as very unstable solution to implement.
2. The .wheelDelta aspect of the event fires asynchronously and is difficult to capture a gesture with. (On chrome, it just spits out a multiple of 3 a bunch of times rather than a distance of the gesture in px). This makes it difficult to set a threshold and animate the elements that are responsive to that threshold.

I basically want to be able to track the number of pixels a scrollwheel-like event is covering and apply that number to the position of a certain scroll-hint element until the scroll threshold is met. Once it is met, a function fires to change the classes and update some information on the page. If the threshold is not met, the scroll hint element goes back to it's default position.

My attached approach doesn't feel very conducive to accomplishing this, so I'm looking for either 1) a different and more stable approach or 2) revisions / criticisms on what I'm doing wrong with this approach to make it stable.

```js
(function scrollerTest($){
 $('body').on ('mousewheel', function (e) {
      
     var delta = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta,
            currentScreenID = $('section.active').data('self').section_id,
              currentScreen = $('section.part-' + currentScreenID),
              nextScreenID = currentScreenID + 1,
              nextScreen = $('section.part-' + nextScreenID);;
 
     if (delta < 0) { // User is Scrolling Down
          currentScreen.removeClass('active').addClass('top');
          nextScreen.removeClass('bottom').addClass('active')
     } else if (delta > 0) { // User is Scrolling Up
        
         
     }
 });

}(jQuery));
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  }
section {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: #CA5D44;
  transition: 0.8s all ease-in-out;
  }
section.part-1 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
  }
section.part-2 {
  background-color: #222629;
  }
section.active {
  transform: translateY(0);
  }
section.top {
  transform: translateY(-10%);
  }
section.bottom {
  transform: translateY(100%);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <section class="part-1 home active" data-self='{ "section_id" : 1, "section_title" : "Home", "menu_main_clr" : "#fff" , "menu_second_clr" : "#CA5D44", "logo_clr" : "white" }'>
  </section>
  <section class="part-2 about bottom" data-self='{ "section_id" : 1, "section_title" : "About", "menu_main_clr" : "#CA5D44" , "menu_second_clr" : "#fff", "logo_clr" : "white"  }'>
  </section>
  <section class="part-3 contact bottom" data-self='{ "section_id" : 1, "section_title" : "Contact", "menu_main_clr" : "#fff" , "menu_second_clr" : "#CA5D44", "logo_clr" : "white"  }'>
  </section>
</body>
```

**Edit Note:** 
The snippet seems to have some issue with firing the event and changing classes after the first instance - not sure why.  On my local example it fires them all at once..

**Edite Note 2: **
Listed code is just a copy of the closest behaviour I could achieve. The whole threshold functionality seems pretty unattainable with this method, unfortunately, as the wheel event doesn't behave like a scroll event.

Comment: Have you considering checking [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)? The most popular library for this kind of things.

Answer (score 0):

the whole scroll topic is rather complex especially when you think about touch scroll events, too.
There are some libraries out there - see this list for example: http://ninodezign.com/30-jquery-plugins-for-scrolling-effects-with-css-animation/

I used https://projects.lukehaas.me/scrollify/ before and it might allow you to do what you intend (using the before callback eventually) but I can't tell without trying myself. Also regard that scrollify is relatively big (8kb minified) in comparison to other libraries.

Comment: This is a great list of plugins, thanks! I'm hoping to get around having to load up dependencies for the code if I can. Ideally I'd like to just build a 'next-screen' prototype function and call it on certain thresholds. Mobile isn't too tough, but getting this effect on a computer is giving me quite a headache. Gonna give scrollify a shot and see if it can get me there effectively

Answer (score 0):

You can approach this using by ensuring each content-filled section is followed by a blank transparent gap (in the example below, also `100vh` in height) and then using javascript to apply `position:fixed` to each content-filled section when it hits the top of the viewport.

**Example:**

```js
var screens = document.getElementsByClassName('screen');

function checkPosition() {

 for (var i = 0; i < (screens.length - 1); i++) {
     var topPosition = screens[i].getBoundingClientRect().top;
    
        if (topPosition < 1) {
            screens[i].style.top = '0';
            screens[i].style.position = 'fixed';
        }
    }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll',checkPosition,false);
```

```css
.screen {
position: absolute;
display: block;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
}

.red {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
}

.orange {
top: 200vh;
background-color: rgb(255,140,0);
}

.yellow {
top: 400vh;
background-color: rgb(255,255,0);
}

.green {
top: 600vh;
background-color: rgb(0,191,0);
}

.blue {
top: 800vh;
background-color: rgb(0,0,127);
}

p {
font-size: 20vh;
line-height: 20vh;
text-align: center;
color: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="red screen">
<p>Screen One</p>
</div>

<div class="orange screen">
<p>Screen Two</p>
</div>

<div class="yellow screen">
<p>Screen Three</p>
</div>

<div class="green screen">
<p>Screen Four</p>
</div>

<div class="blue screen">
<p>Screen Five</p>
</div>
```